# How can I get this function to work in R?

Tags: r, function

```
prob.matrix <- function(tables){

tables <- addmargins(table(titanicData$Pclass, titanicData$Survived))
tables



 l <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)
 l
for(x in 1:3 ){



  l[1:3, x] <- tables[c(1:3), x]/tables[c(4), x]
  l[4, x] <- tables[c(4), x]/tables[(4), 3]


}
 l
}


Pred <- function(Class, prob.matrix){
  if ("FirstClass")
  { Class <- prob.matrix[c(1),3]} 
  else if (class == "SecondClass") { Class <- prob.matrix[c(2),3]} 
  else if (class == "ThirdClass") {Class <- prob.matrix[c(3), 3]} 
  class
}

Pred("FirstClass")
class
```

I am trying to get the second function to work. I want to be able to type in the class of the passenger after Pred in the brackets and for it display the relevant data from my matrix. I cant get it to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: which function? There are two of them?

Comment: The second function @PoGibas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pred <- function(Class, prob.matrix){
    if (Class == "FirstClass") { 
        class <- prob.matrix[c(1),3]
    } else if (Class == "SecondClass") { 
        class <- prob.matrix[c(2),3]
    } else if (Class == "ThirdClass") {
        class <- prob.matrix[c(3), 3]
    } 
  return(class)
}
```

You have to use `return` at the end of your function to return result.